# How long would a plasma trail last during a lander's Mars atmospheric entry?

Tags: mars, reentry, insight, plasma

In this video of the Orion reenty, [ᴴᴰ Full Onboard Re-entry into Earth’s Atmosphere ● New NASA Spacecraft](https://youtu.be/j1vmVJKqUFE?t=19), the plasma trail appears to last about 90 seconds.

Screenshot from video
[image]

Considering how thin the Martian atmosphere is how long would a plasma train be visible?

NASA [illustration](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/timeline/landing/entry-descent-landing/) of Insight's plasma trail.
[image]